# Fast Report VCL CrossObject Conditional Highlighting

Tags: delphi, pivot-table, fastreport

I'm using Fast Report VCL CrossObject.
I have two columns(currency): DeviceHeatingThermalCapacity, ContractHeatingThermalCapacity.
I want to highlighting some columns/rows where DeviceHeatingThermalCapacity is bigger than ContractHeatingThermalCapacity.
For example,  Condition 'Value >20' is work without problem.
But,

```
Value > <frxDBDataset1."ContractHeatingThermalCapacity">
```

is highlight all rows. How correctly use fast report highlighting expressions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the only way to achieve your goal is to use script and handle `OnPrintCell` inside report code or `OnBeforePrintCell` in your application.